# Does the pickleball serving number reset when a point is won at the second serve?

Tags: scoring, pickleball

The score during a game of pickleball doubles is **4-7-2**.

For those unfamiliar, this means that:

- the serving team has **4** points,
- the opposing team has **7** points, and
- this is the second serve for the serving team.

Now suppose that the serving team **wins** the point. The score becomes **5-7**. That much is clear, but:

Does the pickleball serving number reset when a point is won at the second serve?

**Concretely**, does the score become:

1. **5-7-1** (with the serving number resetting to **1**), or does it become
2. **5-7-2** (with the serving number remaining **2** *despite* that this is the first serve to be made at the **5-7** score?

Answer (score -2):

In a game of pickleball doubles, the score 4-7-2 means that the serving team has 4 points, the opposing team has 7 points, and it is the serving team's second serve. If the serving team wins the point, the score becomes 5-7.

The question is whether the serving number resets to 1 after a point is won on the second serve. The answer is no, the serving number does not reset. The score would become 5-7-2, with the serving team still serving their second serve. The serving number only resets at the start of a new game or if the serving team loses a point.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange - however, please note that unnecessary links to your site are likely to get your answer flagged as spam and deleted by the community; I've removed the link in this case.

Comment: Not sure why there are vote-downs.  Thanks for settling this puzzle, but are you sure of this answer? Could you add a few words to describe why you think so?

Comment: @Sam The downvotes were due to the unnecessary link causing the post to be marked as spam.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I see. Aside from SE rules, including the rule preferring answers to be self-contained, I have no issue with external references (including self-referencing), but only if the reference sheds more light on an issue, which is not the case here.